# how can i send dynamically appended value to controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

```
<form id="participantsForGd">
<span id="GroupID"></span> //in here group id is coming example: 2
<button id="GdStartTest">Start test</button>
</form>
```

I want to send the value of GroupID to the controller using Ajax call how can i do that.?
this is my append java script..

```
$("#GroupID").append( group ); //in here Example: group value=2
```

This my controller page call:

```
$("#GdStartTest").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
data: {Gd: $("#participantsForGd").serialize(), 'action': 'startGdstudents', },
```

I want to add that group id in `Ajax data:` or `input type=hidden` form.. how can i do that

Comment: How about `data:{Gd: $("#GroupID").text()....`

Comment: it is coming in consle but in data it is not going can you suggest how to concat variable..? `var groupID = $("#GroupID").text();` i tried this|: `data: { participantsForGd: $("#participantsForGd").serialize(), 'action': 'startGdstudents','groupid':groupID },`

Comment: check answer, i have concat it with some text.

Comment: if you need to fetch another field then you have call val() every time.So using serialize is best way in case of form.So try hidden property and set value rather than text will be best way.

Comment: show my edited code..may be a best way for you...if you want to do like this..

Comment: Update the controller page call section in your question (is not complete).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#GdStartTest").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
data: {Gd: "sometext-"+ $("#GroupID").text(), 'action': 'startGdstudents', }
```

".text()" : will return you the content of the element.

if you want to create hidden input you can do it like:

```
$("#groupID").val(); // this will return you the value

$("#GdStartTest").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
    data: {Gd: "sometext-"+ $("#GroupID").val(), 'action': 'startGdstudents', }
```

Comment: if you need to fetch another field then you have call `val()` every time.So using serialize is best way in case of form.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this...

```
<form id="participantsForGd">
<input type ="hidden" id="GroupID"> //in here group id is coming example: 2
<input type="submit" id="GdStartTest" value="Start test">
</form>
```

And for setting group id..

```
$("#GroupID").val(group);
```

For handing submit...

```
$("#GdStartTest").click(function(){
data = $("#participantsForGd").serialize();
data.action = 'startGdstudents';

$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   data: data,
   url: 
  .......
  .......
});
});
```

And in your php file you can fetch values like this...

```
$id = $_POST['GroupID'];
$action = $_POST['action'];
```

Comment: `serialize()` form values after clicking submit button.

Answer (score 2):

put a hidden input in the form also and it would be included in `serialize()`

```
<form id="participantsForGd">
    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="GroupID">
    <span id="GroupID"></span> //in here group id is coming example: 2
    <input type="submit" id="GdStartTest">Start test</button>
</form>
```

Comment: value="2" is dynamic.